# Unable to create an instance of batteryManager

Tags: android, public, batterymanager

Unable to create an instance of `batteryManager` from `android.os` package if I try to create the instance like below

```
Batterymanager bm = new BatteryManager();
```

What i am excepting is too get the properties via battery manager object but i am getting `Batterymanager is not public` exception

Comment: There is no need to create new instance. The usable properties are static in BatteryManager. So use them as `BatteryManager.SOME_PROPERTY_NAME` something like this.

Comment: But my doubt is why I cannot able to create instance of that? @KaushikBurkule

Comment: The concept is clear that if class is not public we cannot access it outside the package. Batterymanager class in not public in android SDK. This is basic abstraction concept in Object-oriented programming.

Comment: i afraid it is not  public please recheck this link developer.android.com/reference/android/os/…

Answer (score 0):

You could try using BatteryManager like this

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#java

Comment: mam but my doubt i swhy we cannot able to create the instance of that?

Comment: you can get system services in this way--> var battry : BatteryManager = context.getSystemService(
            Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager and you can't create instance from them

Comment: it didnt  mention in any documentation , how did you learn please correct me the persespective of the learning mam

Comment: System services are bridge between system libraries/hardware layer and your application   https://blog.propaneapps.com/android/getsystemservice-from-context-to-android/